# Control+Enter no longer submits a post edit in the Stacks Editor

Tags: bug, status-review, edits, stacks-editor

It's already infuriating that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't submit a new post, this keychord only works when editing a post. Or used to.

With the new Stacks Editor on Meta (doesn't seem to be available on the main site) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does not submit my edited post. Rather, it inserts a new line at the bottom of the text box. Sometimes the final newline cannot be deleted when this occurs, though it does get trimmed from the final post.

Comment: I was never aware that this existed. Maybe this should be a feature request to add a checkbox for this option instead. I imagine this is just an undefined behavior which you got used to.

Comment: It's worked for like 10 years lol, this is kind of a de-facto standard when submitting forms. This is a shortcut that is often never disclosed but works on a number of platforms, and has its roots in MS Office (Outlook in particular). Either way, it worked before and now it doesn't, so I'm reporting it as a bug. SO/SE can do with it what they will.

Comment: Most definitely, describing this feature as "undefined behavior" is just incorrect. Undocumented, sure, undefined, certainly not. `Ctrl`+`Enter` follows the very common pattern of using a modifier key with another to trigger some secondary action in a UI; in this case, pressing `Enter` outright is expected to create a newline in the post editor, and the modifier + enter submits the post, which makes a lot of logical sense. This kind of thing is also is a _huge_ deal for accessibility, where users need to be able to navigate by keyboard.

Comment: The funny thing is it's not like the keychord only enters a newline; it moves the cursor to the last line in the box and adds the newline at the end.

Comment: Also, to clarify my edit, the editor you're referring to is called the "Stacks Editor", which is the new rich text compatible editor, developed first for Teams, and seemingly planned for the main site down the road (described in detail in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033) on Meta.SE). You can [toggle it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHcS1.png) on and off in [your user preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current); I think they opted everyone in recently, as I could've sworn that it toggled itself back on for me a week or so ago after I had it off.

Comment: I mean I have been digging the new editor, this is just an unfortunate regression of it. Also, I don't like how all links are done with the inline syntax instead of listing the links by index at the bottom of the post. My understanding is the latter is preferred, so I've been doing links by hand.

Comment: @zcoop98 Sorry, undefined by Stack Overflow. As there was clearly an oversight in carrying through support for this particular nuance.

Comment: _"Control+Enter no longer submits a post edit in the Stacks Editor"_ [It never did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360075/348196). There are sooo many bug reports and important feature requests (like this one) about the Stacks Editor that are not handled (yet?).

Comment: (Ctrl + Enter inserts a newline for some text controls in Visual Studio's Designer (yes, Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code).)